MongoDB atlas containers not separating from testcontainers
we are moving to mongodb atlas and I've started using the mongodb/mongodb-atlas-local container for local development, it bound to ports 27017:27017. Now I wanted to update our integration tests to use the new container but I have some strange behaviour. This is my old code that worked, there is some extra code so it starts as a replica set so I can test functions that use transactions
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def init_mongo_get_uri():
    mongo_container = DockerContainer("mongo:latest")
    mongo_bind_port = randint(a=30000, b=40000)

    mongo_container.with_name("python_testing_mongodb")
    mongo_container.with_exposed_ports(mongo_bind_port)
    mongo_container.with_bind_ports(container=mongo_bind_port, host=mongo_bind_port)
    mongo_container.with_command(f"--port={mongo_bind_port} --replSet=rs")
    mongo_container.start()

    # normally the stuff above would be enough but we need to start the container with replica set to be able to test functions that use transactions
    # starting with replica set takes a second so we need to wait for the container to be ready
    mongo_uri = f"mongodb://localhost:{mongo_bind_port}/?replicaSet=rs"
    max_attempts = 10
    for attempt in range(max_attempts):
        exit_code, output = mongo_container.exec(
            "mongosh --quiet --eval=\"rs.initiate({_id:'rs',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:%s'}]})\" mongodb://localhost:%s" % (
                mongo_bind_port, mongo_bind_port)
        )

        if exit_code == 0:
            # If the command succeeds, break the loop
            break
        else:
            # Wait for 1 second before retrying
            sleep(1)

        if attempt == max_attempts - 1:
            # If we reach the last attempt and still fail, raise an error
            raise RuntimeError("Replica set didn't get setup properly after 10 seconds")

    yield mongo_uri

    mongo_container.stop()



@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_app(init_mongo_get_uri):
    # Additional check to ensure the MongoDB container URI is not None
    if not init_mongo_get_uri:
        raise RuntimeError("MongoDB Testcontainer URI is None in test_app fixture.")

    # Setup the MongoDBSingleton with the container URI
    MongoDBSingleton._instance = None
    MongoDBSingleton(uri=init_mongo_get_uri, db_name="testdb")
    #start flask app

Now the mongodb/mongodb-atlas-local image uses replicasets by default so supposedly no need for all that extra stuff.
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def init_mongo_get_uri():
    mongo_container = DockerContainer("mongodb/mongodb-atlas-local")
    mongo_bind_port = randint(a=30000, b=40000)

    mongo_container.with_name("python_testing_mongodb")
    mongo_container.with_bind_ports(container=27017, host=mongo_bind_port)
    mongo_container.start()

    mongo_uri = f"mongodb://localhost:{mongo_bind_port}"

    yield mongo_uri

    mongo_container.stop()



@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_app(init_mongo_get_uri):
# same as before

Here my knowledge of either Mongo or docker or both are failing me because even if the new integration tests run against the testcontainer on a different host port I still see the testdb appear inside my local dev 27017:27017 container, and if I stop the tests with debug I can use compass to connect to the testcontainer on say port 37017 and I'll see my local databases there as well.
I have tried binding the atlas testcontainer to something other than 27017 but it seems that isn't allowed.
What am I missing so I can run the testcontainer without it "polluting" my dev-container? I would have thought that having different host ports would be enough.
EDIT
It seems when my local dev db is turned off I can't access the test one at all unless i run it on 27017:27017.

As usual despite trying for hours, I solved it as soon as I asked for help. I'm not sure about the details. Maybe someone can illuminate me, but if I change the connection string to.
mongo_uri = f"mongodb://localhost:{mongo_bind_port}/?directConnection=true"

It works as expected, I can run my tests without the other container running and I don't see testdb appear in my local dev container even if both are running at the same time.

I can explain why that is.
Inside the container, is a replica set. When you connect to a replica set with any of the MongoDB drivers, the driver's SDAM (https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring-logging-and-monitoring.md) kicks in. The driver discovers the replica set and tries to initiate a connection to all the nodes. But the hostname inside the container is assigned based on the container id and is unknown/unreachable from the host. directConnection=true prevents this behavior in the driver.
